# Windows command line: why environment variable is not available after &

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, makefile, environment-variables

Have a look at the following commands: why is the value of a not available immediately after the `&`?

```
C:\>set a=

C:\>set a=3&echo %a%
%a%

C:\>echo %a%
3

C:\>set a=3&echo %a%
3
```

But when I do

```
C:\>set a=

C:\>set a=3&set
```

a=3 is included in the listed variables!

I need this for a trick I learned here, to get the exit code of a command even output is piped:
[Windows command interpreter: how to obtain exit code of first piped command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170753/windows-command-interpreter-how-to-obtain-exit-code-of-first-piped-command)
but I have to use it in a make script, that's why everything must be in one line!
This is what I am trying to do:

```
target:
    ($(command) & call echo %%^^errorlevel%% ^>$(exitcodefile)) 2>&1 | tee $(logfile) & set /p errorlevel_make=<$(exitcodefile) & exit /B %errorlevel_make%
```

But errorlevel_make is always empty (the file with the exit code exists and contains the correct exit code).

Is this a bug in cmd? Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Create a batch file and call the batch file in the make script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's much easier to create a seperate batch file to solve this, as it isn't obvious even for experts.

But in your case this should work

```
target:
    ($(command) & call echo %^^^^errorlevel% >$(exitcodefile)) 2>&1 | tee $(logfile) & set /p errorlevel_make=<$(exitcodefile) & call exit /B %^errorlevel_make%
```

A seperate batch could look like

**extBatch.bat**

```
@echo off
("%~1" & call echo %%^^errorlevel%% > "%~2") 2>&1 | tee "%~3" & set /p errorlevel_make=<"%~2" 
exit /B %errorlevel_make%
```

Then you could start the batch from your make file

```
target:
    extBatch.bat $(command) $(exitcodefile) $(logfile)
```

Comment: The altered line does not work either, but using a separate batch script is a good idea! I have to figure out how to execute a command given as a command line parameter, or I have to create the batch dynamically.

Comment: Do you get the correct data in your temporary file? At which point it seems to fail?

Comment: I added some carets to the one line solution, it works in my test-makefile.

Comment: Yes I did already get the correct data in my temporary file. Thanks to @MC-ND 's answer I also understand why it does not work anyway. Your one line solution still does not work for me, but your batchfile does. Maybe we have different make.exe or OS, I should have mentinon that I use gnu make and win7. But does not matter, I will use a batch file, thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The reason for the observed behaviour is how the command line is processed.

In first case `set a=3&echo %a%`, when the line is interpreted BEFORE EXECUTING IT, all variables are replaced with their values. a has no value until line executes, so it can not be substituted in echo

In second case, `set a=3&set`, there is no variable substitution before execution. So, when set is executed, a has the value asigned.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the nice answer of jeb, I modified the code a little to be able to grab errorlevel for each side of the pipe, separately. For example you have the following pipe in your batch file:

```
CD non_exisitng 2>&1 | FIND /V ""
ECHO Errorlevel @right: %errorlevel%
```

The errorlevel above refers to the right-hand side of the pipe only, and it indicates if the FIND command succeeded of not.
However, to be able to get the errorlevel of both sides, we can change the above code to something like this:

```
(CD non_exisitng & CALL ECHO %%^^errorlevel%% >err) 2>&1 | FIND /V ""
ECHO Errorlevel @right: %errorlevel%
SET /P err=<err
ECHO Errorlevel @left: %err%
```

**output:**

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
errorlevel @right: 0
errorlevel @left: 1
```

@OP:

I realize this comes a bit late, but might be helpful for others. In addition to jeb's method of an external batch file, the original problem can also be solved as one-liner:

```
target:
    ($(command) & call echo %%^^errorlevel%% >$(exitcodefile)) 2>&1 | tee $(logfile) & set /p errorlevel_make=<$(exitcodefile)  & cmd /c call exit /B %%errorlevel_make%%
```